# Angular directive ng-repeat input set focus to new option added using add button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, autofocus

I have an html page with question and ability to add multiple options   with ability to add or remove an option.

How wanted to set focus to the newly added option text box which was added using add button/link

Here's the link for [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CzI3Mw?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.question = { question: 'what is your name',
     options: [{option:'Red', code: '1'}, {option:'Blue', code: '2'},
     {option:'Green', code: '3'},{option:'Black', code: '4'}]};
});

app.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {

                function Option() {
                    this.option = '';
                    this.code = '';
                }

                scope.addOption = function(index) {
                    var existingOption = scope.question.options;
                    if (existingOption && existingOption.length) {
                        var newOption = new Option(index + 1);
                        scope.question.options.splice(index + 1, 0, newOption);
                    }
                }

                scope.removeOption = function (index) {
                    if (index > -1) {
                        scope.question.options.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                }
            },
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {
                question: "="
            },
            templateUrl: 'question.html'
        };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an autofocus directive that will give focus to an element when it is first created:

```
.directive('autofocus', function($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
                element.focus();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Then in question.html add the autofocus attribute to the input:

```
<input type="text" autofocus class="form-control... />
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/xW17yIgEaKS0oX4wVj23?p=preview

Comment: In this case when I have some more form elements on page the focus is set to last option automatically. I should have focus to option only when I require or add anew option. http://plnkr.co/edit/3O0pc7EoODjinCuPvPgW?p=preview